# Why using weak typing array for Vector, ArrayList and the whole Java collection framework

Tags: java, generics, strong-typing

I am wondering why didn't the Vector api (as well as others) choose to use strong typing for its underlying array like the code below ? why using week typing Object ? isn't it better with strong typing as the type safety is resolved in compile time ?

```
public class Vector<E> {
    private static final initialCapacity = 2;
    protected E[] elementData;

    private Vector(Class<E> c) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final E[] elementData = (E[]) Array.newInstance(c, initialCapacity);
    }   
}
```

Comment: i mean not specifically to Vector but in general

Comment: There'll need to be an unchecked cast somewhere, whichever way you do it...

Comment: what would you suggest as more "type-safe" alternative ?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth agree, but one is checked, and one is unchecked, right ? my actual question is why go for unchecked ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vector`, `ArrayList`, and the whole collections framework was written before generics were a thing in the first place.  They didn't really have an alternative at that point, and it had to be left that way for backwards compatibility.

Comment: so that sounds like strong typing is better, it that right ?

Comment: A lot of things can be better in Java, but contractually you'd be breaking principals of an API, which is to not remove, but replace or improve. Java does just that, it doesn't break its own API (usually).

Comment: Eh.  It also requires having an explicit `Class` object, and means you can't actually make it work with nested generics: you can't enforce the typechecking of a `List<Foo<Bar>>`.